# How do I create a range-like function in which the arguments are controlled by input data

Tags: python, pygame, range

We're making a science outreach game using Pygame in which players add or remove marbles (which represent a hormone) onto a Hx711 scale, a raspberry pi measure the weight to create a value, and a character on the screen gets larger or smaller depending on the amount of marbles/hormones.

I already have a list of images (playerimages) and I've created a loop which increments through the list of images to show an animation of the character getting bigger, and I know how to blit a single image during the index as a reference.

So my idea was that I have a function (say def weightdata) which takes the weight value and creates a reference to an index in the image list. Then I have another function that takes the weightdata, and if the startweight/index is less/more than the next weight value (endweight/index) then the image indices of the animation either increases or decreases from the startweight image to the endweight image. I've tried this:

```
startindex = 14

endindex = 29

running = True

while running:
      if startindex == endindex:
          running = False
      elif startindex < endindex:
           self.image = self.playerimages[startindex]
           self.index +=1
      elif index > endindex:
           self.image = self.playerimages[startindex]
           self.index -=1
```

I expected the animation list to move from index 14 to index 29 but when I run the code it just shows a blank screen which I have to force to close.

Comment: @michael basically covers the problem in the answer below.  But the example code does not show the calls to initialise pygame, nor update the screen, nor any handling of user-input for window-closure.  Do you have all the usual pygame interface code working ?  I would have expected that if the code was working ok (despite the above problem), you still should be able to quit the window normally, not "force" it to close.

Answer (score 4):

During the loop the startindex and endindex are unchanged, therefore the condition will always be the same, in this example:

```
  elif startindex < endindex:
       self.image = self.playerimages[startindex]
       self.index +=1
```

This should probably be `startindex += 1` instead of `self.index`